# Why is getting a video from the URL not working PHP?

Tags: php

So I wanted to make a video sharing site and I have to get the id of the video somehow. So I added a script that should do the trick:

```
    <video id="video" controls width="640" height="480" poster="play.jpg">
        <source src="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['videos'], '/' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" type='video/mp4;' />                                                
        <embed src="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['videos'], '/' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" wmode="opaque">                                                   
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />                                     
        </embed>
    </video>
```

But of course it doesn't work (for some reason).

I was expecting the code to get a video from `/videos/` on the server and echo the basename of the video into the `source` and `embed` tags. Though it displayed a blank video.

Comment: View page source, what is generated/rendered? This is open to XSS injections

Comment: `$_SERVER['videos']` is unusual - have you pro grammatically modified the `$_SERVER` variable? What is the rendered path (ie: view source of webpage) - does the path look anywhere near correct? Can you supply an example of the querystring?

Answer (score 1):

you have syntax errors
try this code:

```
<video id="video" controls width="640" height="480" poster="play.jpg">
    <source src="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['videos']).'/'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" type='video/mp4;' />                                                
    <embed src="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['videos']).'/'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); ?>" wmode="opaque">                                                   
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />                                     
    </embed>
</video>
```